# Call function from another page in php

Tags: php, html

I have a `form` that user can update their details on `page-1.php`.

After user submit the `form`, it will got to `page-2.php` for validation and update database if user input is true.

May i know how to call a function from `page-2.php` and display the error message on `page-1.php`. Below are the function on `page-2.php` that I use to display the error message:

```
$_SESSION['err_msg'] = array();
function addError($msg) {   
    $_SESSION['err_msg'][] = $msg;
}

function printErrors() {
    foreach ($_SESSION['err_msg'] as $err){
        echo "<ul><li><span style='color: red;'>".$err."</span></li></ul>";
    }
    unset($_SESSION['err_msg']);
}   
//other codes for the validation and update
```

if i use `printErrors();`on `page-2.php`, it will display the error message

Answer (score 1):

You need to include page-2.php in page-1.php. [Read this about that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

The best way is to put all your functions in one seperate file, like functions.php and include them on every page with an include.

Answer (score 0):

I think no you don't need function on page-2.php. You can simply check session variable on page-1.php. If $_SESSION['err_msg'] exists and count is greater than 0. Then you can print all errors to page-1.php>
Please check below code.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['err_msg']) && count($_SESSION['err_msg'])>0 ){
foreach ($_SESSION['err_msg'] as $err){
    echo "<ul><li><span style='color: red;'>".$err."</span></li>    </ul>";
}
unset($_SESSION['err_msg']);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks.. it is working but I need to refresh the page to get the error message. Is there a way for not refreshing the page? For your codes, when I clicked on submit, it does not display any message but when I refresh the page, it will show the error message.

Comment: You will add above code to page-1.php file, when you come back from file page-2.php using php headers, then errors messages will automatically display.

Answer (score -1):

Include the page-2.php in your page-1.php

Comment: Same as @JKMurray's answer.

Comment: tanga ng hayop na ito

Comment: if i need to include page-2.php in page-1.php, do i have to just call the the function in page-1.php like `printErrors();` after i include the page or i need to do something else?

Comment: You can call the function directly.